# How to pass SAML assertions in jenkins to scripts used in jobs?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, scripting, saml, assertion

On Jenkins we had connected [SAML Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/SAML+Plugin) with our Authentication System.
But we would like to pass authetications data (SAML assertion) to other scripts, so they could also authenticate their activities or simply work with already created authentication. So ...

... how to pass SAML assertions in Jenkins to scripts used in jobs?

Are there any extra plugins, which might expose more e.g. environment variables, or is there any other API to get the assertion?

BTW some other Authentications plugins seems to be dead projects:

- [OAuth Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/OAuth+Credentials)
- [OAuth Credential Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/OAuth+Credentials+Plugin)